# How to create a cycle slideshow without the jerk/pause

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've used this code below and it works perfectly but I can seem to figure out how to stop the jerk from occurring at the beginning. I've been trying to figure it out but I'm very new and can't seem to do it without help. I want the slideshow to be in a constant motion/loop without any pause/jerk at the beginning.  Does anyone know how to do this?!

Thank you!!

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx=carousel data-cycle-timeout=1000 data-cycle-carousel-visible=6 data-cycle-carousel-fluid=true data-cycle-slides="div">
  </div>
  <div class="span2">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYmwYO

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following jQuery in your JS.

$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle({
    speed: 2000,
    manualSpeed: 1000,
});

This will set a transition speed for you (speed: 2000 = speed in milliseconds). There are also some other thing to try, like "ease" in the documentation. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

If you want a more agile carousel, try http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Its a very powerful, light-weight, and easy to use carousel

Answer (score 0):

You could use bxslider for this kind of slides :
http://bxslider.com/examples/ticker